# Laravel - created new MySQL user, updated env with user details, old user still making connections

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Because of a security issue, I had to create a new MySQL user for our Laravel app.

I created a new MySQL user (in phpMyAdmin) and added all the necessary privileges for our database.

Then I went into Laravel's `.env` file and changed the MySQL user/password. Then I did

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

After that, the MySQL logs still indicate that the old user is making all the queries from the app. What else do I need to do? I'm reluctant to restart the `mysqld` process because I don't want to reset my global variables.

Comment: You could check if the `.env` variables are read in https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/config/database.php#L52-L53

Comment: You also could try to run `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: And who is consuming those credentials in your app? Is it a Worker (job)? Then you never restarted your workers. And what global variables do you have on a database that you could lose if you restart the engine? That is not good at all, if by any means it restarts alone, the host server goes down, whatever, you lose them anyways, what do you have in there that you cannot risk losing?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Nothing I cannot risk, just some buffer/cache vars that I'd have to reset. The app backend, as well as cron jobs, are consuming the credentials. Should I just restart Apache?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Yes it's read

Comment: @svetipetar I am not following because if it is just buffer/cache (hope you are correctly using the cache, so losing it does not risk losing unresolvable data) you can definitely restart any engine/system like Apache, MySQL (or your database server), Redis, whatever you are using and needs to be reloaded so the new credentials are used. Have in mind that, if you have updated the `.env` (and you have no OS environment variables set) and run `php artisan config:clear` or just `php artisan config:cache` (you should always cache the config on PROD only), then MySQL, Redis, etc will not care

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes you're right, I've restarted mysql and apache with no issues - however the app (and crons) are still using the old mysql user.

Comment: Be careful that restarting apache (or your webserver) does not mean that all your PHP processes get restarted. If you are running `php artisan queue:work` or any similar (or `php artisan horizon`), then it does not use the webserver, so a (or more than one) PHP processes are running in the background and need to be restarted. I am 100% sure you have a job workers in the background and you need to restart them either using `php artisan queue:restart` or `php artisan horizon:restart`. If `horizon:restart` does not exist, run `horizon:terminate` and then run `horizon` again